# What is the least a human needs to survive and remain concious?

Tags: surgery

This question is rather morbid, but I have been asking it myself for quite some time.

My thought process was this: If someone removed my limbs, I'd still be able to survive. Other non-vital organs, such as my eyes, could be removed as well and still allow me to remain concious.

So after repeating this process, what would the "minimal human" look like?

Note: If this is off-topic here, please tell me which site would best be suited for this question.

Comment: [Only the brain is needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat)

Comment: Is this currently possible? Or would the brain die sooner than average due to complications?

Comment: I don't think we can pull this off today, but there are serious attempts to getting to brain transplant (whole body transplant), which involves keeping the brain alive outside the body for a while.

Comment: So with the added constraint of "what's possible today", how would that change the question?